# Ubuntu 16.10 infinite boot animation

Tags: boot, scripts, plymouth

So i have been bumping my head with this over the past 2 days. I have a virtual box in which I installed  16.10 and i need to make a custom Plymouth boot animation but the trick is that the hard drive will be encrypted and i need the animation to run for ever so the user will not get into the system. just to be able to see the infinite loop of the boot animation. Any ideas of how i can make this happen via a self running script?

Comment: or at least how can i increase the duration of a custom boot animation?

Comment: So i take it that no1 knows how to do this. been trying to do this for 1 week now....plymouth does not have this option....the boot time is still unchanged....i just want to increase the boot time at the splash screen logo